# Get a full height div from where it starts according to the window

Tags: html, css

This question is more project specific. I have two `<div>` in my template which looks like this.

[image: Two Divs]

I want that last div to acquire full height respective to window from its vertical position. 
For example,

[image: Two Divs]

If I add another div, it should look like this.

[image: Three Divs]

Right now in this example, I am setting height explicitly just for demonstration purpose.

How can I make the last div calculate height according to its vertical position and all content should be visible inside the window.

Comment: Go look into flexbox, it is pretty easy to achieve using that.

Comment: you can take second div outside the first row class div

Comment: Rather than showing loads of screen shots of code, please can you create a [mcve] of your code otherwise your question is off topic and will be closed

Comment: As they said, Flexbox it's a very simple CSS solution, and friendly with media-queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this. The flow is `column` so the div's are vertically aligned. The last div get a `flex:1` to expand.

`flex:1` or `flex:1 1 0%` is a short writing for:

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

For your last div the flex-grow and the flex-basis is important.

See [flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  background: #ccc;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
}

.container>div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understood your example, but need more clarity about flex:1 . I mean, how its actually working.

Comment: see my edit. You allow the last item to use the remaining space. Also important is, that the container div have the 100% height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; /* where you want to start; */
  bottom: 0; /* (the end) */
  left: 0;
  /* you can use width 100% or code right:0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  somethin
</div>
```